# How to Change datatype of all column to Unicode datatype for all base table in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Due to storing values from language specific diacritics (Spanish, French, German) I am trying to change the datatype of a column to Unicode datatype.

- Varchar to nvarchar
- char to nchar

So all column datatype to its respective  Unicode datatype.

For all tables in a specific database.

Can it be possible to do in a single statement? Because doing with `alter` statement is time consuming.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee 
ALTER COLUMN FirstName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You have alter each column individually. You could write a script to extract the column names and build and run the alter statement. There are many examples of this around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we create a temporary table and define the variables we need for the changes.

Then we fill the table by fetching the columns that need to change.
I entered the fetch command below and everything is clear.

Then, for each row in the table, we make the desired changes in the database.

Also, a column in a table may have a value of `NULL`, so you must replace the `NULL` values with a value before changing the column.
I replaced the `NULL` values with a value of `0`.

The code below works perfectly and correctly.

***Only I entered `dbo` for `schema name` in search of columns. See what your database schema name is***

```
--Container to Insert Id which are to be iterated
Declare @temp1 Table
(
  tablename varchar(100),
  columnname varchar(100),
  columnlength varchar(100),
  columntype varchar(100)
)
--Container to Insert records in the inner select for final output

Insert into @temp1 

SELECT t.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME,c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,c.DATA_TYPE FROM information_schema.tables t
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c on t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t.table_schema='dbo'
and (DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' OR DATA_TYPE = 'char')

-- Keep track of @temp1 record processing
Declare @tablename varchar(100)
Declare @columnname varchar(100)
Declare @columnlength varchar(100)
Declare @columntype varchar(100)
Declare @SQL VarChar(1000)
Declare @vary varchar(100)
Declare @final varchar(1000)

While((Select Count(*) From @temp1)>0)
Begin


  Set @tablename=(Select Top 1 tablename From @temp1)
  Set @columnname=(Select Top 1 columnname From @temp1)
  Set @columnlength=(Select Top 1 columnlength From @temp1)
  Set @columntype=(Select Top 1 columntype From @temp1)


  if(@columntype = 'varchar')
    Set @columntype='nvarchar'
  else
    Set @columntype='nchar'
  --set null value with 0 value

  SELECT @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @tablename + ' SET ' + @columnname + ' = 0 WHERE ' + @columnname  + ' IS NULL'
  Exec ( @SQL)


  SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE '
  SELECT @SQL = @SQL + @tablename
  select @vary = ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @columnname + ' ' + @columntype + '(' + @columnlength + ') NOT NULL'
  select @final = @sql + @vary

  --select @final
  Exec ( @final)

  Delete @temp1 Where tablename=@tablename and columnname = @columnname
End
```